# Which JavaScript or ASP.NET Charting Component/Tool/Library Will Work For This?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-mvc, controls, charts

**[Update]:** *Forgot to include ComponentArt...*

Hi,

An interaction designer employed by the client I am currently working for produced some mock-ups, and now it is my job to determine the best way of implementing the charts included therein.

After looking at the options I am aware of and was able to find doing some simple Google searches, I have narrowed it down to using either **ComponentArt**, **Dundas Charts** or **Infragistics**, simply because from what I can see of their demos, they have certain features I believe I will need to get things done.

Here are the pictures from the mock-ups - ideally I need one piece of software that will cover all of these:

---

[image]
**This chart seems to be simple enough.**

---

[image]
**Notice the arbitrary spacing between the years - not yet sure if this will be a sticking-point for the client or not.**

---

[image]
**I don't know that I have ever seen a chart like this one - it combines the previous chart with some additional data.**

---

[image]
**Here is the same chart, only this time illustrating what happens when a user mouses-over or clicks on an annotation within the chart. They want the nice styling within the pop-up, so the pop-up needs to be something like an iframe or similar. Obviously, as long as a control supports client-side events, with associated metadata, I can create the pop-up myself.**

---

Any ideas or recommendations would be appreciated, I haven't used charting controls in *years*, so I am at a bit of a loss and the client wants an estimate soon.

Thank you!

Comment: have you had a look at flot? - http://code.google.com/p/flot/ Some of the examples you have above might not be handled so well by it

Comment: Yes, I did look at that, but it would take more work to make it do what I need it to do. Ultimately, I could make something work; I am not afraid of, or averse to, enhancing controls to get things to work, but this project is on a very tight schedule (they want it very soon and the charting is really the only "hard" part) and I worry about having the time.

Comment: The Dundas charts now included in asp.net include most of the above functionality in an individual chart but the layered chart seems to be quite a bit more complex and I'm not sure if you could do that without alot of work.

Comment: You should also take a look at .netCharting http://www.dotnetcharting.com/ there is a gallery that shows you all the things that you can do including the code to do it. It might be worth a look.

Comment: +1 for Jonathans suggestion for the MSChart Control available in .NET itself (separate installable for .net 3.5 and integrated with .Net 4.0)

Comment: You can also consider Nevron Chart (www.nevron.com) it has some pretty good AJAX capabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raphaël (http://raphaeljs.com/) is also really nice and powerfull.

Comment: WOW - that is an awesome little library. Thanks, I may not end up using it, but this is the kind of thing that could make it work if I end up with the time to do such custom work.

Thank you!

Comment: So, I am still unsure if this will become a reality, but I am going to mark your response as the answer, because after looking it over, I think that JS library has the most potential for being able to actually implement the charts with the least work. Hopefully I will be able to completely validate that in the next week!

Answer (score 1):

If you are ready to spend few hundreds, I would suggest you to choose adobe flex charting components.

They are pretty cool with tones of features in them.

I'm using adobe's flex charting component in all my projects after using YUI charts, which has very limited features.

Comment: Can't use that because I have to support the iPad and iPhone. *&@#^$!! Steve Jobs and his Flash hatred!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Google charts and visualizations APIs or MilkChart for Mootools

Comment: Insufficient for my needs, but thanks - I need to use a more robust, ready-to-go product; with those tools, I may be able to hack something together, but I don't have the time need for that, notwithstanding the fact that it might be a fun thing to do. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

[DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/Charting/) also have charting components which should be on par with Infragistics or ComponentArt.

For a couple of charts that we use in both a WinForms and WebForms application that required some pretty hairy features, we used the [ProEssentials Charts](http://www.gigasoft.com/) from Gigasoft...The best feature of the ProEssentials charts was that the support was by far the best of any product we've ever used (charting or non charting). We received email replies within 24 hours no matter what issue we had or day/time of week etc from people who know exactly how it was...however, the cost of the controls is definitely at the higher end...

Answer (score 0):

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_to_jquery_visualize_accessible_charts_with_html5_from_designing_with/

this would be the JavaScript chart I'd like to recommend. however it seems you may still need to do a little bit custom coding, to meet the requirement you need

Answer (score 0):

Telerik RadCharts are also a good option..they allow advanced charting features...and also work good with AJAX